# Change text of QStandardItem when editing starts

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qstandarditemmodel

Using Qt4's model/view framework, I have a list of items displayed as "Foo (38 bars)". I want to make the text editable, but when the user starts editing, I want the control to just show "Foo" (the name), and then to reinstate the extra info "(38 bars)" when editing is complete.

I think I can work out how to add the info back, but is there a way to change the text of the item when editing starts?

The model is a QStandardItemModel, and the items are fairly trivial subclasses of QStandardItem. They are displayed primarily in a QListView.

The UI is written in PyQt, and I'd prefer not to dive into C++ just for this, but I'll do my best to translate C++ solutions if they appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After @Chris put me on the right track, I found this note [in the docs for QStandardItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#data):

> The default implementation treats Qt::EditRole and Qt::DisplayRole as
>   referring to the same data.

So I needed to override the method `QStandardItem.data()`. My Python code looked like this:

```
def data(self, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return "{} ({} bars)".format(self.name, len(self.ds))
    return super().data(role) # Fall back to the default method
```

On the model's `itemChanged` signal, I updated the .name attribute I'm using:

```
def update_name(self):
    self.name = self.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
```

Finally, the number of "bars" can be changed elsewhere, and this should trigger any views to update the item. So after changing that, I called the `item.emitDataChanged()` method ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#emitDataChanged)).

With this done, it seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set the Qt::EditRole data on your items to achieve this. In C++ it would be:

```
myStandareItem->setText( "Foo (38 bars)" );
myStandardItem->setData( Qt::EditRole, "Foo" );
```

When Qt sees something in the EditRole, it will use that for editing purposes instead of text (which is stored under the Qt::DisplayRole).

You can then use things like the QStandardItemModel::itemChanged() signal to update the display text of the item when it gets edited.

Comment: Does `itemChanged()` signal has to be emmited when starting to edit? You should call `myStandardItem->setData( Qt::EditRole, "Foo" );` only once, and only then `signalChanged();` should be emmited.

Comment: This was the key I needed to see how to approach the problem. I've written up what I actually had to do as a separate answer, because there's a bit more to it.